# Fabric.js: Window Resizing Issue

Tags: html5-canvas, fabricjs

I'm trying to make a simple PowerPoint-like app. I'm struggling window resizing issue for this two weeks. I really appreciate it if you give me any advice!

I want to keep locating a white rectangle in the middle of a screen so I use absolutePan and zoomToPoint. It works perfect when it's loaded. However, when you resize window the position is drifting.

Here is my code

```
.
.
  handleWindowResize()
  window.addEventListener('resize', handleWindowResize)
.
.
  function handleWindowResize(){
    var clientWidth = document.getElementById('drawing-area').clientWidth
    var clientHeight = document.getElementById('drawing-area').clientHeight
    canvas.setDimensions({ width: clientWidth, height: clientHeight })

    // Pan canvas to locate white board center
    let panX =  - (canvas.width - WB_WIDTH)/2
    let panY =  - (canvas.height - WB_HEIGHT)/2

    var zoom = Math.min(canvas.height/WB_HEIGHT, canvas.width/WB_WIDTH) * 0.9
    canvas.absolutePan(new fabric.Point(panX,panY))
    canvas.zoomToPoint(new fabric.Point(canvas.width/2, canvas.height/2), zoom)
    canvas.renderAll();
  }
```

I think panning works out but zoomToPoint function doesn't work correctly. The center point of zoom doesn't seem to be correct.

I tried relativePan, setViewportTransform, and some other functions, but no luck.

Please help!

[screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/srxDg.gif)

[Codepen: my code](https://codepen.io/fyusuke/pen/abwQOXR)

Answer (score 1):

finally I solved this issue.
Must set Zoom = 1 before panning

```
    var zoom = Math.min(canvas.height/WB_HEIGHT, canvas.width/WB_WIDTH) * 0.9
    canvas.setZoom(1) // Must set zoom = 1 before panning
    canvas.absolutePan(new fabric.Point(panX,panY))
    canvas.zoomToPoint(new fabric.Point(canvas.width/2, canvas.height/2), zoom)
    canvas.renderAll();
```